# Resources Being Blocked HTTPS Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

We recently moved our application into HTTPS domain but now all our content being served from server is being blocked

This is the following message we are getting for all:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:8443/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://localhost:8080/resources/css/base.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

In our html we call this via the following line:

```
<link th:href="@{/resources/css/baseline.css}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Can anyone help us figure out how we supposed to serve our css/js and other content and have it work in https environment.

FYI we are using Spring MVC as our App Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this could mostly be because of many reasons,few of which as mentioned below, could help you figure out the issue in your application :

1.If you have a context for example such as https://localhost:8443/{context}/login
  and the other css/js/image content are being served via thymeleaf,then most probably you have a security set which does not allow https://localhost:8443/css and so on for images and js.

2.If you have spring security enabled ,then you could be blocking the /css or /js or /images via the role/request url handler.Kindly check your security java configs or spring-security.xml or so.

3.If you have a web server or a proxy loadbalancer behind you requests ,please allow /js and /css and /images from base path ,for example :

ProxyPass /js
ProxyPassReverse /js
...and similarly for css and images

Other than the above mentioned scenarios there could be also some proxy or security configuration that prevent the page from loading the css/js/images content.

Hope it helps!!